# rotate text 330 degree in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is it possible to rotate text in IE

```
-moz-transform: rotate(330deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(330deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=330deg);  /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=330deg)"; /* IE8 */
```

lines written for IE are not working.

Can any one help.

**EDIT.
I want to rotate text crossed**

Comment: Try this :.. filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

Comment: @suresh.g how do you expect `(rotation=3)` to rotate 330 degree?

Comment: We unable to set this, but we can use rotation=1 or 2 or 3. It will works like 90,180,270..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already pointed out, the solution you want depends on the targeted ie version.

You should use all the transforms with different vendor prefixes

```
-vendor-transform : rotate(330deg);
```

and for  ie versions that do not support css rotation, you can convert the rotation into a `filter matrix` and apply  it to the element.
 [Here's a site](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) that automatically converts the css3 transform to a filter matrix :

```
 /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.8660254037844387, M12=0.49999999999999994, M21=-0.49999999999999994, M22=0.8660254037844387, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
        M11=0.8660254037844387,
        M12=0.49999999999999994,
        M21=-0.49999999999999994,
        M22=0.8660254037844387,
        SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

The only downside is that in order to make the transform-origin the center of the element, oyu must provide the width and height of that element.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, rotation in IE is only possible in 90 degree intervals.

Check docs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried in this way:

```
<div id="rotation">Try this rotation</div>​

#rotation
{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=..);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg);    
  width:100px;
}​
```

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velthune/MAN4g/184/)

Comment: His question states he needs an answer for IE; those provided by you are for webkit (Chrome / Safari) and moz (Firefox).

Comment: What supposed to replace the two dots in `rotation=..` to make it rotate 330 degree?

Answer (score 0):

Try this new example..

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.8660253882408142, M12=0.5, M21=-0.5, M22=0.8660253882408142,sizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE6-8 */
```

This has working

if you want more rotation angle means visit http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/filters/matrix.htm

Comment: OP wants to rotate 330 degree, not 270

Comment: -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.8660253882408142, M12=0.5, M21=-0.5, M22=0.8660253882408142,sizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE6-8 */

Comment: why you put me down rating?

Comment: Because the question is "how to rotate 330 degree in IE" and you gave the answer "(rotation=3)" - I notice you have changed your answer and will remove my downvote :o)

Comment: is this answer useful for you?

Comment: Your answer is similar to the answer given by gion_13 so I guess it is working. You can always test it at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) if in doubt.